# Vertica : Cannot allocate sufficient memory for COPY statement (536870912 requested, 268435456 permitted)

Tags: database, vertica

I'm getting this error while trying to run a copy table command to load a JSON. I also tried creating a resource pool with higher MAXQUERYMEMORYSIZE, QUERY_BUDGET_KB, and MEMORY SIZE value but still getting the same error. How to ensure that the query was run on a specific memory pool?

below is the command:

```
copy_user=> copy test_load from local '/home/dbadmin/test.json' PARSER fjsonparser() rejected data as table test_load_rejected;
ERROR 2344:  Cannot allocate sufficient memory for COPY statement (536870912 requested, 268435456 permitted)
HINT:  This can happen if you have very wide rows, or if you have specified an incorrect record terminator.
       (Check your escaping -- for example, "'\t'" is not a tab; you must use "E'\t'".)
       It can also happen if you are reading from a corrupted compressed file

dbadmin=> SELECT query_budget_kb FROM resource_pool_status WHERE node_name ilike '%0001%' ORDER BY query_budget_kb desc;

 pool_name | memory_size_kb | max_memory_size_kb | planned_concurrency | max_concurrency | query_budget_kb 
-----------+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------
 copy_pool |              0 |          173225413 |                   1 |                 |       164564128
```